# CSS 3 nth-child(n) doesn't work #table_id td a:nth-of-type(n)

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<table id="table_id" > 
<tr>
<td><a href="/"><img src="http://images1.png""></a></td>
<td><a href="http://x.com" >xx</a></td>
<td><a href="http://y.com" >yy</a></td>
<td><a href="http://z.com" >zz</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and selector to change the link color and style

Why this one works

```
#table_id td:nth-of-type(2) a
{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

but not this one?

```
#table_id td a:nth-of-type(2) 
{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all can be explained if we define what these CSS selectors are doing.

First selector (working):

```
#table_id td:nth-of-type(2) a
```

*Translates to:*

> Find me any element that has the id `table_id`.  Anywhere under that, then find me the second occurence that is a `<td>`  Then find me an `<a>` anywhere under that.

This selector matches because:

```
<[**table id="table_id"**]> 
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/"><img src="http://images1.png""></a></td>
    <[**td**]><[**a**] href="http://x.com" >xx</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://y.com" >yy</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://z.com" >zz</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Second selector (not working):

```
#table_id td a:nth-of-type(2) a
```

*Translates to*:

> Find me any element that has the id `table_id` and then under that, find me *any* occurence of `<td>`, then under that, the *second occurence* of the type `<a>`.  Finally, find an `<a>` under that.

This doesn't match because:

```
<[**table id="table_id"**]> 
  <tr>
    <[**td**><a href="/"><img src="http://images1.png""></a></td>
    <[**td**]>
      <a href="http://x.com" ></a>
      <[**a**] href="this matches. because it's the second nth-type">
        <[**a**] href="this is the actual element you'd be selecting with that selector."></a>
      </a>
    </td>
    <[**td**]><a href="http://y.com" >yy</a></td>
    <[**td**]><a href="http://z.com" >zz</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we look at **#table_id td:nth-of-type(2)**.  With **#table_id** as the parent, **td:nth-of-type(2)** targets the 2ND **TD** child.  That is, it targets

```
<td><a href="http://x.com" >xx</a></td>
```

But **#table_id td a:nth-of-type(2)** looks at **td** as the parent, and therefore targets the 2ND **A** child.  However, every **a** in your code is the 1ST child of it's **td**, and therefore is not targeted.